# Exact sequence $A\hookrightarrow B\to C\to\cdots$ and kernel

Tags: exact-sequence

Given an exact sequence
$$
0\to A\to B\overset\alpha\to C\to\dots
$$
is
$$
\ker\alpha\cong A
$$
true? I feel that the answer is trivially "yes, by definition" but I couldn't find this expression anywhere so now I'm in doubt.

Anyway, I'm interested in the case where these are groups, and ideally the $\cong$ refers to a group isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.  Since the map $A \to B$ is monic, its image is isomorphic to $A$. But its image is equal to $\mathrm{ker}(\alpha)$ by exactness.